# Retrieve or Read Existing SQL File - C#

Tags: c#, database, sqlite, win-universal-app, assets

How do I retrieve or open data from existing sqlite file? I have a sqlite file with the name kamus.sqlite in asset folder.

The database has columns id, word, translation. I want to show the word and the translation column in listview.

Answer (score 0):

For using SQLite in UWP you need to use some wrapper library.

Read this article:

[Using SQLite on the Universal Windows Platform](http://blogs.u2u.be/diederik/post/2015/09/08/Using-SQLite-on-the-Universal-Windows-Platform.aspx)

It's works. But only library name is changed. From [SQLite Download Page](https://www.sqlite.org/download.html) download VSIX package for Universal Windows Platform.
And after installing and adding reference package you can install from NuGet wrapper [SQLite.Net-PCL](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SQLite.Net-PCL/)

Or you can use [Portable Class Library for SQLite](https://sqlitepcl.codeplex.com/). I have used this library. Here is simple example how to create a table:

```
using SQLitePCL;

 using (var conn = new SQLiteConnection("Storage.db"))
            {
                string sql = @"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS People (
                                            ID INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
                                            FirstName NVARCHAR(50),
                                            LastName NVARCHUAR(50));";
                using (var statement = conn.Prepare(sql))
                {
                    statement.Step();
                }
            }
```

To insert records run query:

```
using (var statement = conn.Prepare("INSERT INTO People (FirstName, LastName) VALUES ('John', 'Doe')"))
                {
                    statement.Step();
                }
```

or you can use params:

```
using (var statement = conn.Prepare("INSERT INTO People (FirstName, LastName) VALUES (?, ?)"))
                {
                    statement.Bind(1, "John");
                    statement.Bind(2, "Doe");
                    statement.Step();
                }
```

To read rows:

```
List<string> column=new List<string>();
using (var statement = conn.Prepare("SELECT LastName, FirstName FROM People WHERE FirstName='John'"))
    {
       while (statement.Step() == SQLiteResult.ROW)
        {
   // here you can add value into collection for example
column.Add(statement[0]); // statement[0] - is value of first column
        }
    }
```

Comment: But that sample to make its SQL and stored in local package. While I need is read sqlite in assets folder on the solution.

Comment: In this case just change Path to Path.Combine(Package.Current.InstalledLocation.Path, @"Assets\Storage.db")) like in example from @Damir-arh

Comment: How do I take the existing tables in the database? Because in that sample, create a new table.

Comment: How do I retrieve data from a column in the table in sqlite? Because the sample makes the contents of the table.
 
and how to take the existing table from database? Because the sample is create table (not to take the table from database)

Comment: @Rose, I have update answer once again. Take a look at last code sample (for reading rows)

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can do it using the [sqlite-net-pcl](https://www.nuget.org/packages/sqlite-net-pcl/) NuGet package:

- Install the package into your project.

  ```
  Install-Package sqlite-net-pcl
  ```
- Create a class corresponding to your database table:

  ```
  // the name of the class must match the name of your database table
  // the names of properties must match your column names
  public class Localization 
  {
      [PrimaryKey]
      public int Id { get; set; }
      public string Word { get; set; }
      public string Translation { get; set; }
  }
  ```
- Load all the data from the table into a list:

  ```
      using (var connection = new SQLiteConnection(Path.Combine(Package.Current.InstalledLocation.Path, @"Assets\kamus.sqlite")))
      {
          var records = connection.Table<Localization>().ToList();
      }
  ```
- Use the list as needed, e.g. bind it to a `ListView`.